# Is synchronized access to non-volatile fields thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, volatile

I am unable to find this particular scenario answered anywhere.

If I call `init()` simultaneously from two threads, is one of the calls guaranteed to see that the `time` is not null anymore? Does `time` need to be `volatile` as well?

Does it work like `join()` which is a synchronisation point?

```
private Long time;

synchronized void init() {
    if (time != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already initialised.");
    }

    this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: I think if the variable is non-volatile there can be problems with caching on multiple processing units.

Comment: If this wasn't thread-safe, `synchronized` would be completely useless.

Comment: *Synchronized* keyword implicitly implies a *Happens before* relation ship. So, yes, it is thread safe.

Comment: Are you saying that **all** variables touched within a `synchronized` block are immediately visible to all future `synchronized` blocks on the same object even if they're not `volatile`?

Comment: @Locutus - yes. Because Synchronization creates a memory barrier which forces data to be fetched from main memory rather than from the cache. So, Whatever data changes in the synchronized block, it is visible once you exit the block.

Comment: @Locutus - Which variables are *touched / changed* in the synchronized block doesn't matter. *Everything* will be read from the main memory. So, using Synchronization where it is unnecessary is bad (performance will be affected..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a thread enters this `synchronized` method, it acquires an `implicit` lock over the instance, the changes it performs to the `state` of the instance is visible to the other threads, waiting to enter the synchronized method.

> when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a
>   happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a
>   synchronized method for the same object. **This guarantees that changes
>   to the state of the object are visible to all threads.**

The last line in the docs mention it clearly. It doesn't matter if the state were `volatile` or `non-volatile`.

Comment: What if instead of being a `synchronized` method, I wrapped the statements in a `synchronized(lockObject)` block? Now I am changing the state of some other object than the lock object.

Comment: Yes, in that case it cannot be guaranteed. Then you could make use of the volatile keyword.

Comment: You're pulling a quote out of its context. Having a synchronized block does **not** guarantee that changes are visible to **all** threads, only to threads that *have subsequently acquired the same monitor using a synchronized block*. The quote was only valid in the context of the example class `SynchronizedCounter` on the page where you pulled your quote from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html (not you are required to attribute where you take quotes from)

Comment: It still stands good for Threads sharing the same instance and an instance method being synchronized?

Comment: @BatScream yes, but only for the threads that have later acquired the synchronized block (and only after they have done so)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt So code within `synchronized(lockObject)` calls will see changes to **any** variable that they've previously changed no matter which thread they're called on?

Comment: @Locutus any variable that was changed while the code that changed was synchronized on the same object. The really tricky thing here is that in 99% of the cases, it will also seem to work in many other situations. But then suddenly when you are using multiple threads with heavy CPU loads, it stops working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is use the static class initialiser.

```
 class TimeHolder {
       public static final long time = System.currentTimeMillis ();
 }
```

The assumption being that you init either when the class is used the first time or when the object is created.

Comment: It's just an example. I need thread safety for something else.

Comment: The more realistic the question, the more appropriate the answer.